# How to get predicted values from performing CV.SuperLearner in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that I'm performing stepwise regression on, with cross validation.. I originally performed multiple linear regression with cross validation, and was able to see how close the values were for my test set to my training set for each fold (I used the value to then plot a graph in which I measured the performance). I was to do the same thing, but with stepwise regression. I performed the following algorithm in R:-

```
test <- CV.SuperLearner(Y,X, V = 10, SL.library = SL.library, verbose = TRUE, method = "method.NNLS")
```

but I can't see how I'm able to look at the values from each fold and how close they were. Is there a way of me being able to do so?

I tried `print` and `summary`, but they don't give the information I want.

Thanks

Comment: You should note that you are using the SuperLearner package, and please provide a reproducible example. It looks like your object test is an object with components SL.Predict, discreteSL.Predict, and library.predict. I would have a look at those components. See the help page for more information about the components.

Answer (score 2):

That is explained in `?CV.SuperLearner`: 
the result contains an `AllSL` slot, with all the folds.

```
# Sample data
library(SuperLearner)
example(CV.Superlearner)

str(test$AllSL)             # You see a list with V=10 elements
test$AllSL[[1]]             # The first fold
predict( test$AllSL[[1]] )  # The predicted values
```

If you want to compare with the actual values, 
you need to know which observations were included in the fold.

```
plot( 
  Y[ test$folds[[1]] ],
  predict( test$AllSL[[1]] )$pred,
  xlab = "Actual", ylab = "Predicted",
  main = "First fold"
)
```

More generally, to examine the contents of an object, you can use `str` and `names`
in addition to `print`, `summary` or `plot`.

```
str(test)              # Too long to be useful
names(test)
str(test$AllSL)
str(test$AllSL[[1]])
str(test$folds)
```